# Copy image with src="dataUrl" to Office application

Tags: html, canvas, base64, data-url

Trying to copy an image to clipboard doesn't seem to work corectly if the image is using a data-URL.
(tested on IE9, Chrome 25.0.1364.152)

I seem to be able to past "Data-Url" images to paint. 
Pasting to Word/Excel fails. unless the paste special option is used.

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dw9sD/2/)

Using a Data-url as source is a common scenario when trying to save images rendered on a canvas element. There is a work around by saving the image to disk first. Is there a way to enable these images to be copied directly to word, not using the paste special option?

inspecting the image properties in IE9 shows us:

```
Protocol: Unknown protocol
Type: Not Available
Size: Not Available
```

whereas the normal image

```
Protocol: HTTP
Type: JPEG Image
Size: 12897 bytes
```

I think these properties usually come from the headers in a request. 
Is there a way to set these properties for the data-url image? I think it should be able to be pasted directly into Word when these properties are set.

Answer (score 2):

In MS Word, there is a way,

Object>> Insert Object >> New Bitmap Object>> And then in new window paste and close the same,

the working is same as paint but option available within word, and that works fine,

For Excel I am sure the same will work,

I hope this will satisfy your need.

Within same application your work will get done

:)

Comment: Found it under Paste >> Paste Special >> Bitmap. This works, Although if anyone knows how to enable the image to be pasted with a regular ctrl + v. I would love to know.

Comment: I had tried that(Ctrl + V) but does not work in Microsoft office :)

Comment: Hence the question. I'm wondering what's causing this behavior. and if we can set any properties to make it the image behave like a regular img.

Comment: Its Meta data>> data stream, that is easy for browser to understand as it deals with same, but for word editor, its not designed for the same, so we need to identify the type and have to deal with it accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize Lars's answer in the form of shortcut keys:

1. Press `Ctrl + Alt + V`;
2. Select **Bitmap** with `Up` or `Down` key;
3. Press `Enter`.

That's it!